Parallel block cipher in CTR mode and variable number of threads: how to deal with internal state and permit decryption?
I'm implementing a parallel block cipher (Morus, to be precise) in CTR mode and I'd like to make it flexible with respect to the number of threads. It is not difficult per se, as I can partition the message and distribute chunks to any number of threads quite easily, since CTR mode permits an embarrassingly parallel implementation with basically no challenges. However, I'm not sure how to ensure decryption correctness when it happens with a different number of threads with respect to encryption.
Let's say a user decides to encrypt their message with 2 threads (T1 and T2), and let's say, for simplicity, that my implementation assigns the same (IV, key) pair to every thread. The message M is divided in two chunks M1 and M2 and each chunk assigned to a thread for encryption. Let's say that these chunks can be conceived as being divided in two sub-chunks each M1 = [M11,M12] and M2 = [M21,M22] (it will be useful later).
When T1 begins encrypting sub-chunk M12, its cipher's internal state will depend on the previous steps, i.e., initialization with (IV, key) and encryption of M11. This state will have an influence on the produced output, there will be "an echo" of it in the encryption of M12.
Overall, the 2 threads will produce C = Encr(M), with C = [C1,C2] and, again, C1 = [C11,C12] and C2 = [C21,C22], with Cij = Encr(Mij). Now, let's say that the same user attempts decrypting C with 4 threads (T1, T2, T3, and T4). When T2 tackles its chunk decryption (C12), it will have a freshly initialized cipher with (IV, key). Basically, it will decrypt its chunk in a different state with respect to the one in which it was encrypted.
In this situation, will decryption be successfull? I'm afraid it won't. I'm afraid it will have the same effect as decrypting with the wrong IV or key. I think that, in a parallel implementation, either one of these two conditions should hold:

Decryption should happen with the same number of threads as encryption;
Each thread should conceive its chunk as a sequence of independent blocks, thus re-initializing its cipher at each block's encryption/decrpytion.

I hope I'm wrong in this. 1) is not a nice solution, as it implies the necessity of a further "contract" between encrypting user and decrypting user (what if encryption is done on a GPU and decryption on an embedded board?). As for 2), it is not good either... in Morus, a state update is needed after each block encryption/decryption, but an initialization requires 16 rounds of state update!
Any thoughts? Is there a way to solve this nicely?

I think you misunderstand how CTR should be implemented in parallel. You should not divide the plaintext into "chunks" but rather blocks instead. These blocks are the block size of the encryption algorithm. CTR mode uses the key to encrypt the nonce/IV + counter. Then the encrypted nonce/IV + counter is XORed with the Plaintext block of same size. There are no "sub-chunks". Each block is assigned to a thread. This ensures that the counter will always be the same for each block regardsless of the number of threads. I.e. each thread is assigned key, nonce, counter, block.

This seems like a security and crypto protocol/mode question more than a programming question, so it's probably off-topic. But, similar to the previous comment, I'll note that introducing parallelism should be an implementation detail. The result should be the same as doing standard CTR mode encryption using a single thread. You're talking about changing the protocol, and doing so in an insecure way. For example, if you use the same (IV, key) pair for two or more different chunks, that's completely insecure! Also, CTR mode desperately needs a MAC, which can't be parallelized.

@SaniHuttunen thank you. This clarifies a lot. Basically, the "state update" that is performed after each block encryption is harmless seen this way, because every thread has its cipher (identical to the others') that just encrypts one block and somehow dies.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I wasn't attempting to change the protocol! It's just that, having a message to encrypt, some granularity should be selected (that's why I was talking about chunks). Sani's comment clarifies: that granularity is the single block, thus after-encryption state-updates are not only harmless, but useless.

@biagiop1986: I took a look at Morus today and unfortunately for you, the "after-encryption state-updates" is not harmless or useless. The StateUpdate after each block actually prevents implementing a parallel Morus! This is due to that each block depends on the current state and the state is updated after each block is encrypted. I wrote an implementation of Morus today and I cannot see that it could be parallelized. This is the thing with authenticated ciphers, they are not "normal" block ciphers.

@SaniHuttunen thank you, now it's way clearer for me. At this point, I was wondering (I understand we're in the opinion realm now and I'm probably O.T.): imagine a slightly different protocol, in which the input is divided in blocks, each encrypted in a CTR-like mode in different threads. A tag is generated for each block and then combined together with a transitive, commutative function into one. What should one prove that it is as secure as the original protocol? What function would be a good choice?

@biagiop1986 That is essentially ECB mode since you will have to give all blocks the same nonce. In that case the "tag" is useless and no longer the same algorithm.
